# How to isolate the asset with errors when precompiling Rails assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm getting this error when trying to precompile my Rails application assets:

```
Unexpected token: operator (*) (line: 424, col: 9, pos: 14566)
```

I have many individual CSS and JS asset files. How do I know which one this erroneous "*" token was discovered in?

```
xxx $ rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
xxx
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Unexpected token: operator (*) (line: 424, col: 9, pos: 14566)
```

Comment: i guess i can just remove them all and add them one by one as i precompile the assets. but is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake assets:precompile:primary --trace`, which will or will not pass.
If it not pass, sometimes it shows another error message, which could help.

If it pass, search in  `public/assets` the problematic file. It will not be minified so you can look at  "falling" line (eg. `[line 424, col: 9,]`) and try to find the error.